# using ipdb for debugging python inside emacs

Tags: python, emacs, pdb, ipdb

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` works fine when I run 
`M-x pdb

python manage.py runserver`

However `import ipdb` would cause the above statement to hang indefinately..

I hear great things about ipdb, how do I use it under emacs?

- Edit

Just found out django has nothing to do with it, simple python file hangs as well.

Comment: See my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806204/using-ipdb-with-emacs-gud-without-explicit-breakpoints-in-code/31232014#31232014